# Zend Framework setNoRender into plugin

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

Is there any way I can add this to my plugin?

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

Comment: What kind of plugin? What's the point of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do it from anywhere using static method call:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper("ViewRenderer");
```

Comment: how to setNoRender?
Like this?
`$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper("ViewRenderer");
$viewRenderer->setNoRender();`

Comment: "Didn't work" covers a lot of possibilities, so more details is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need:

`Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('viewRenderer')->setNeverRender(true);`

EDIT (request from danielhanly.com):

If you want this code:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

to work in plugin (`preDispatch()` method) you need to change it to:

```
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('viewRenderer')->setNeverRender(true);
```

Its similar to  rjmcb method, but instead of `setNoRender()` (which does not work) you have to use `setNeverRender(true)`

Comment: Please explain this, as opposed to just dumping a line of code. It'll help future visitors if you do :)